# Boolean toggle using rails_admin on list view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-admin

I have a basic rails_admin application and would like to be able to toggle a boolean value in the *list view* of rails_admin.

For example, I have a scale model with an attribute 'activated'. When I log in to the rails_admin dashboard I see the scale model and the lists of various scales and the activated attribute with the boolean value.

How would I make this value editable in list view so I can change the boolean value from this view so I don't have to go in to the *edit view* to edit the value?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I made a gem some time ago exactly for that purpose - [rails_admin_toggleable](https://github.com/rs-pro/rails_admin_toggleable)